# Convert milliseconds to Firestore date

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In Flutter I convert dates to milliseconds like this:

```
static DateTime createDateTimeNow() {
    return DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
        DateTime.now().day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

// This create a number value like 1660341600000
final Number millisecondsNow = Helpers.createDateTimeNow().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

// I can also format is as String to be presented based on the language
final String dateNow = DateFormat.yMMMMd(language).format(millisecondsNow);
```

Now I have Firebase Cloud Functions that should read these dates and send notification when they expire, but could I convert this number to a normal date in Firestore?

From Flutter I do something like this:

```
final DateTime dateNow = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1660341600000);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normal date in Firestore"?  Are you saying you want to read or write a timestamp field?  It might help if you explain your use case in more detail, and how you are making use of Firestore.  BTW Firestore works just fine if you want to use numbers for dates.

Comment: dateTime in Flutter are different to the dateTime in Firestore so that's why I ended up saving it in milliseconds. My cloud function needs to read it but before that I have to convert it into a dateTime from milliseconds.
Could you explain a bit more about does it work with number if it's not really necessary? I just started with these cloud functions

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you store milliseconds as number in Firestore and you'd like to convert it into a `Timestamp` in a NodeJS Cloud Function?

Comment: Correct. I need to remind them about the events they created before the date expires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fromMillis( )](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#static-frommillis) method  from `firestore.timestamp` which can create new timestamp from the given number of milliseconds.

```
firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(milliseconds)
```

You can refer these documents for more details [firestore timestamp from milliseconds](https://www.zditect.com/blog/55726312.html) and [Firestore Timestamp](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/timestamp#fromMillis)

Answer (score 0):

You're working too hard.  Firestore Timestamp to Dart DateTime:

```
final dt = aTimestamp.toDate();
```

and from DateTime to Timestamp:

```
final ts = Timestamp.fromDate(aDt);
```

as described in https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp-class.html

and there's no need to think about "milliseconds".

Comment: Good to know, but right now I have tons of events saved with milliseconds so I still need that conversion  from milliseconds to Timestamp